# What should I do to mint 2000 items?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, remix, transactions, gas

When I try to mint 2000 items in remix I get this error:

> Gas estimation errored with the following message (see below). The
> transaction execution will likely fail. Do you want to force sending?
> execution reverted

What should I do to mint 2000 items?

This is where I specified the number 2000:

```
contract TST is ERC721Enumerable, Ownable {
  using Strings for uint256;

  string baseURI;
  string public baseExtension = ".json";
  uint256 public cost = 0.05 ether;
  uint256 public maxSupply = 2000;
  uint256 public maxMintAmount = 2000;
  bool public paused = false;
  bool public revealed = false;
  string public notRevealedUri;
```

https://github.com/HashLips/hashlips_nft_contract/blob/main/contract/SimpleNft_flat.sol

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xeHXb.png]

Comment: There's such a thing as a maximum block gas limit. No single transaction can consume more gas than this limit.

Comment: As Paul says, you need to split your mint actions to several Ethreum transactions.

Answer (score 1):

Maximum `gasLimit` on Evm-based(Ethereum) is **30 million gas** for a TX. you can specify higher gas limit on your remix IDE.

in large number of minting you may be faced with large amount of gas to pay because it has too state changes.
the alternative way is that proceed minting with more than one transactions and separate them.